# Developer License Agreement required to develop Google Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, licensing

What kind of license agreement is required when someone develop Google Chrome extensions?

In the case of iPhone, there are "iPhone Developer Program License Agreement".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5):

None whatsoever. However, when you upload your application to the Chrome Web Store, you agree to the [Google Chrome Web Store Developer Agreement](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/terms).  If you self-host your application, you don't have to agree to anything (except for the ordinary software license(s) for use of Chrome/Chromium, and that has no direct bearing on application development).

Apple requires you to accept their license agreement as a prerequisite to getting development tools. Without developer tools, you can't make any iOS apps, especially since iOS has a scheme prohibiting apps from being distributed outside of their app store.

Chrome has none of these restrictions.  Anyone can start developing for it with no barriers to entry. In fact, there are no developer tools, really, other than the extension packer; if you want to start developing Chrome apps, just set up a `manifest.json` and start making Web pages that use their JavaScript API.  And while the Chrome Web Store is probably where you'll get the most exposure, you are free to host your Chrome app anywhere you like with no penalty or restrictions.